# Django related query filter, search for items with and without any related items

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

I'm after a django query that will allow me to list all items which do and do-not have any certain related objects.

For example if I have the models:

```
def Customer(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    ...

def Order(Model):
    customer = ForeignKey(Customer)
```

Now, how do I say "Give me all customers with orders, and conversely, give me all customers without orders"?

What I have so far (which doesn't work) is this:

```
withords = model.objects.all().annotate(orders=Count('order')).filter(orders__gt=0)

without = model.objects.all().annotate(orders=Count('order')).filter(orders__lt=1)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

**All customers with orders:**

`Customer.objects.filter(order__isnull=False).distinct()`

**All customers without orders:**

`Customer.objects.filter(order__isnull=True)`